# How to link combobox when many selections?

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox, vba

I am trying to create an Access Form that links one combobox to another so that the selection made in one combobox determines the next comboboxes' dropdowns. Here is the code I have:

```
Private Sub Combo58_AfterUpdate()

With Forms("UserForm").Combo60
    If IsNull(Forms("UserForm").Combo58) Then
        .RowSource = ""
    Else
        .RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [BusinessLvl2(Unit)Code] " & _
                     "FROM HRBI " & _
                     "WHERE [BusinessLvl1(Group)Code]=[Forms]![UserForm]![Combo58];"
    End If
    Call .Requery
End With
```

End Sub

My code works successfully when there are less than 16 drop down selections. After that, I receive the error message "System Resources Exceeded". I assume I am hitting Access limitations, however this seems like a really simple task to try and accomplish. Does anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong and a workaround?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Amend the 'list rows' property on the property sheet of the combo box to what you need.